# On the 1/2 assumption on concentration of measure on continuous cube

Tags: probability-theory, geometric-probability, concentration-of-measure

The concentration of measure on $ [0, 1]^n $ equiped with normalized uniform measure $\mu_{\infty}$, 
states for any $A \subset [0, 1]^n $ with $ \mu_{\infty}(A) \geq \frac{1}{2} $,
we have: 
$$ 1 - \mu_{\infty}(A_{\epsilon}) \leq e^{- \pi \epsilon^2 }, \epsilon > 0, $$
where $A_{\epsilon} = \{ x \in [0, 1]^n; d(x, A) < \epsilon \}$, and $d = L_2$ is the Euclidean distance.

I wonder how the assumption $ \mu_{\infty}(A) \geq \frac{1}{2} $ affects the statement: 
do we have a sharper inequality for $\mu_{\infty}(A) = 0.9$? Do we have a weaker inequality for $\mu_{\infty}(A) = 0.05$?

More precisely, the concentration of measure on $L^p$ balls has the following properties. 
Let $B^n_{p}$ denote a $p$ ball with $\mu_p$ normalized uniform measure,
where $p \geq 2$. 
For any $A \subset B^n_{p} $, with $ \mu_p(A) > 0 $, we have:

$$ 1 - \mu_p(A_{\epsilon}) \leq \frac{1}{\mu_p(A)} e^{-2n C\epsilon^{p} } $$ where $\mu_p(A)$ directly affects the concentratioon bound,
and $A_{\epsilon} = \{ x \in B^n_p; d(x, A) < \epsilon \}$, and $d = L_p$ is the $p$ norm.

Comment: To not blur the main question, I leave this minor detail in the comment. I have looked at a proof in the $L_p, p < \infty$ case. It uses the uniform convexity property which does not generalize to the cube. But I don't know how this may help my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked this question on math overflow and now it is answered:

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/292343/on-the-1-2-assumption-on-concentration-of-measure-for-continuous-cube/292439#292439